# Legacy Biztalk App:Replace webservice schema into Orchestrations and maps

Tags: biztalk

I have legacy BizTalk app that have about 10 orchestrations and 20 maps built on external webservice schemes.Now this old webservice will be removed and replaced with new web-service with similar (almost the same) schemes.

What would be best strategy to replace schemes from old webservice into all orchestrations and maps ? I can go through every orchestration and replace all message types ports and transformations manually. 
Is there better way ?

Please advise.

ACK:I know that more convenient way of building BizTalk applications is to create internal type (xsd) and design all orchestrations and maps around internal type.Than create one map to transform from external(webservice) type to internal, so in case of changing web-service only this one map will be changed.
Unfortunately this is not the way legacy app was build.

UPD:
problem is that old webservice types are being used into a lot of orchestrations and maps. if I pull old webservice out and import new webservice I will get an error in all of them.So I have manually change all of them for using new type. I'm trying to find a way to cheat and not to change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> new web-service with similar (almost the same) schemes.

If that is indeed the case, you probably don't have to replace much if anything.  Just update the existing BizTalk app with the 'minor' changes to accommodate the new service.

However, if the current schema is used in multiple places, you can just use a Map on the Receive Port to transform the new message to the old one.  It perfectly fine if the Root Element and Namespace are the same, all you would need to do is set the old one explicitly in the XmlDisassembler.  Maps always work on the .Net Type only.

Comment: problem is that old webservice types are being used into a lot of orchestrations and maps. if I pull old webservice out and import new webservice I will get an error in all of them.So I have manually change all of them for using new type. I'm trying to find a way to cheat and not to change them.

Comment: @WorkGamificationApp  So you may have to go through all the effort now, and maybe even do the internal schemas and use multi-part message types in the Orchestrations. That way it makes it easier for someone else at a later date to update.